# Split flash Arduino nano

Tags: arduino-nano, flash

I need to update the firmware over-the-air for `Arduino nano`. For that I need to split the flash into two so that one of the partition that contains the original code cannot be erased while re-flashing and the other partition will contain the segment in which the re-flashed program would appear.

The board reboots from the `first partition before the flashing initiates`, during flashing the code in the first partition would be active and the board `reboots from the new code in the second partition after the flashing is complete`.

I don't have any idea how to play around with the flash splitting in arduino and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You'll need to look into creating your own bootloader. As only the bootloader can write to flash.

Comment: According to your plan it will be quite hard to do........ But infact you could do one thing that is change the arduino's bootloader a bit that is increasing the timeout of  the bootloader where it decides to whether go for flashing or go for proccessing the program.....